# After running updates in 10.10 Netbook Remix, Ralink 5390 Not working

Tags: wireless, 10.10, drivers

Additional Drivers still lists the driver. Reports it as being activated but not in use. Prior to running updates, wireless was working fine. Set it up using this guide: [How To Install Drivers For Ralink Wireless Network Devices Under Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-install-drivers-for-ralink.html)

Thoughts and reflections would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

OP reported in [Revision 2 of the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/220730/revisions) that the following action worked for him:

- Use [synaptic-package-manager [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic)
- Mark the driver for re-installation
- Re-install the driver
- Reboot